# Conference issue >> Rejected paper is still in the database/submitted

Tags: conference, plagiarism, rejection, ieee, self-plagiarism

Last year I submitted a paper in a local IEEE conference. The paper was rejected. This year I have a plan to submit the modified version of the paper in another conference. When I checked the file in Turnitin, I found that it is already been submitted in that conference by that university. The university put the file in their repository.

I emailed the organizing committee and they gave the following reply

> “Since, it was (university_name) who organized the ICCIT, and the original paper was checked through (university_name) account for ICCIT, that is why the matching shows (university_name) name there. It is standard practice that if one submitted a paper to any conference and it is checked in the TurnItIn, then it should be in the repository.
>   You may inform the other conference (where you are submitting) that this paper was once submitted to ICCIT at (university_name) and it was rejected. You may send them the rejection notification of ICCIT as the proof.”

This means I always need to inform the conference committee with a separate email that I submitted the paper previously and this paper was rejected. And Turnitin will always give me reply that it is a plagiarized work.
Please share your opinion and suggest me what can I do.

Comment: Shared opinion: Well, that is annoying, both to you and to the conference committee, as you generate more work. You say that the paper is online, but not under your name but rather under some university account? Can you maybe contact said university about removing it? (Unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with TurnItIn, so I don't know how deleting papers there works)

Comment: they are telling me "It is standard practice that if one submitted a paper to any conference and it is checked in the TurnItIn, then it should be in the repository." How can it be!!!

Comment: Assume you submit a paper to a conference and it gets send to reviewer R, who is an expert on your field. The paper gets rejected, however, R found your ideas really interesting, as he is also working on this field. A few months later, R publishes a paper that copies most of your results. As your paper never got published, it might actually seem like original work - and it might take you (as maybe the only one who can tell that it is plagiarism) years before you stumble over this paper.  That's just an idea on why it might be good to leave even rejected papers in the database...

Comment: No, my rejected paper is still in their database and that's why turnitin is finding similarities

Comment: Is the paper in a database at TurnItIn or at the university? Either way, did you try to get it removed (you being the author and holding the rights and everything...)?

Comment: I think, It should be in university database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59974/discussion-between-bemte-and-nusrat).

Comment: **What is your actual question?**

Comment: Is it the case that rejected conference paper will always reside in the database?